# BIOS / Mobo won't detect anything beyond 8GB RAM

Tags: memory, bios

I have a situation where I have a system with 16 GB of physical RAM, but at the BIOS level only 8 GB are detected. There are 4 sticks of G.Skill Ripjaws 4 GB DDR3 1600 MHz RAM. The motherboard is an ASUS P8B75-V LGA 1155 with an Intel Core i7-2600K Sandy Bridge. I built this system in 2012.

[image]

I have taken all RAM sticks out and then one by one I have tested them individually on all RAM slots on the motherboard. All sticks work on all slots and 4 GB is detected by the BIOS. All RAM sticks seem to be good and so are the RAM slots on the motherboard. Only when I have more than 2 sticks inserted is when the BIOS does not detect anything beyond the 8 GB.

[image]

My OS is ArchLinux, but that is not relevant here because the BIOS does not detect the full 16 GB of RAM.

Any ideas or obvious settings that I am missing in the BIOS configuration?

Comment: well i checked the mobo website, that ram *should* work

Answer (score 2):

According to [Intel i7 2600K](https://ark.intel.com/products/52214/Intel-Core-i7-2600K-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_80-GHz) specification your processor doesn't support DDR3 1600 MHz chips (only DDR3 1066/1333). This may cause compatibility problems.

I had similar problem at laptop. When I change Ram for slower it solved problem.

Comment: Good thought.  I checked the mobo, which supports that memory, but I didnt think to check the CPU.

Comment: Oh yea, my sandybridge 2500k used DDR2.

Comment: @lluke  excellent point and i was not aware of that. I must point out that this bios/mobo did detect the full 16 gb up until 6 months ago.

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot shows that your BIOS version is quite old. The latest BIOS would be version 1608.

I recommend updating the BIOS first before checking other possibilities.

Comment: Excellent point and i will try a bios upgrade this weekend